# Output multiple class attributes in 3 columns in Python 3 for 2 or more instances

Tags: python-3.x, format, output

I've been trying to make a text-based horse racing competition consisting of many 1v1 races. I want the user to be able to see the "history" of the competition, as in, who won each race, who lost, and by how much. I though I would store this attributes inside a class Race and all instances of race would be stored in a list.

I found a piece of code from the book "Python for Absolute Beginners" that gave me something like this:

```
for race in race_record_list:
    races = ["{0!s:10}".format(race.winner, race.loser, race.margin)]
    output = """   Winner: {0}   Loser: {1}      Margin: {2}""".format(''.join(races), race.loser, race.margin)
    print(output)
```

Honestly I have no clue how this deals with the blank spaces, but the first 2 columns (winner and loser) look perfectly well aligned (as shown below), while the third one does not.

```
Winner: Brooke       Loser: Audrey      Margin: 2
Winner: Samantha     Loser: Elizabeth      Margin: 10
```

I'd be truly grateful if someone could tell me how to fix it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
for race in race_record_list:
   races = ["{0!s:10}".format(race.winner, race.loser, race.margin)]
   output = """   Winner: {0}   Loser: {1:10}      Margin: {2}""".format(''.join(races), race.loser, race.margin)
   print(output)

Winner: Brooke       Loser: Audrey          Margin: 2
Winner: Samantha     Loser: Elizabeth       Margin: 10
```